# Machine Check Exception?

Tags: boot, 15.10

I'm a novice on ubuntu but have been running an intel NUC for the last month with Ubuntu 15.10. 
This morning everything seemed fine but when i start it now it just goes into some kind of boot loop. Every now and then i get the following error message, see attached screenshot. 
After googling around a bit it seems to be a hardware failure? But how do i figure out which hardware? 
I've tried the following with no success:
Removing one stick of ram and then the other.
Removing the m2 drive with ubuntu on it.

Every time i've removed a piece of hardware i've tried starting the system and starting with a bootable usb with the ubuntu installer. Nothing works.

Any tips are greatly appriciated!

[image: ErrorStuff]

Some updates:
I've exchanged the RAM from two corsairs to two brand new kingstons (same size etc) but it didn't do any difference. I've also tried disconnecting the both hardrives one by one but still the same problem. Does this mean that its the motherboard thats the problem?

Comment: I believe, but am not sure, that your primary issue is the firmware not loading due to the stepping info problem, and that your machine check exceptions are secondary. I have no idea if [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103351) a relevant reference for you or not.

Comment: Wow, i've read that entire thread and understand almost nothing... how do i disable the stepping?

Comment: You can not disable the processor step, but you might be confusing that with intel speedstep, which you would disable in your BIOS. Actually, that would be a good test for you to try.

Comment: It should be under `Power` and should be called `Enhanced Intel Speedstep Technology`. see [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/desktop/sb/biosglossary_nuc_v05.pdf), page 6.

Comment: I tried disabling it but still the same errors!

Comment: O.K. Sorry, I guess your root issue is something else.

Answer (score 1):

A MCE (**Machine Check Error**) is a type of computer hardware error that occurs when a computer's central processing unit detects a hardware problem.  This usually indicates you might have a hardware issue.  Usually when I've encountered an MCE I have a bad stick of memory but I can't be certain this is your problem.

Please run [a memory test](//help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest).

Comment: I've replaced both the memory sticks with new ones so i doubt its the RAM thats faulty....